# Terminal-based text editor for Linux with few dependencies

Tags: gratis, linux, open-source, text-editor, text-processing

I'm using an old(ish) SLES Linux machine on which there are some issues with `vi` which I won't go into. I want to use another text editor - but none is installed as part of the distribution, and I'm not the root user.

Browsing GitHub briefly, I find a few editors I could theoretically build on my own - but they depend on all sorts of modern stuff (e.g. [micro](https://github.com/zyedidia/micro) needs the Go language supported) which itself is probably not installed.

So, I need an editor which I could build from source and is modest in its requirements - not many packages, and things I would likely find on a 12-year-old machine (which does not have many `-dev` packages installed).

It's ok if the editor's build system pulls packages it needs itself.

Comment: See also [Minimal terminal editor alternative to vi and nano](https://askubuntu.com/q/577741/561230).

Comment: You don't need the Go language installed to run the precompiled  binary of the micro editor. Just tried it myself

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @BeloumiX's answer:

[GNU Nano](https://www.nano-editor.org/) (named after the non-free editor it imitated, pico) is a simple curses-based text editor. Working with it is based on various (not so many) keyboard shortcuts, like Ctrl+O for writing the file, Ctrl+W for searching and Ctrl+X for quitting. It takes up the whole terminal, and has a small "menu" at the bottom presenting some shortcuts relevant for the current editing state.

[image]

It has very modest dependencies, except perhaps for one: the [GNU ncurses library](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/), version 5.x (not 6.x!). The development files for ncurses are typically *not* installed, so you will likely need to download some ncurses-5.x version from [here](ftp://ftp.invisible-island.net/ncurses/).

Both the ncurses library and nano build using autotools. Also, you want to build and install to a user-specific path; and you have the dependency. Plus, the ncurses build is [finicky when it comes to C++](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/565722/34868) (which you might not even have a compiler for).

So, let's suppose you want to install nano with `$HOME/opt/nano` serving instead of `/usr`. Here's what you do (with the current versions at the time of writing):

```
NANO_ROOT=$HOME/opt/nano
cd $HOME
wget ftp://ftp.invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-5.9.tar.gz
tar xvf ncurses-5.9.tar.gz
rm ncurses-5.9.tar.gz
cd ncurses-5.9
./configure --prefix=${NANO_ROOT} --without-cxx
make
make install
cd ..
rm -r ncurses-5.9
wget https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v4/nano-4.7.tar.gz
tar xvf nano-4.7.tar.gz
rm nano-4.7.tar.gz
cd nano-4.7
bash
export LDFLAGS="${NANO_ROOT}/lib:${LDFLAGS}"
export CFLAGS="-I${NANO_ROOT}/include ${CFLAGS}"
./configure --prefix=${NANO_ROOT}
make
make install
exit
cd ..
rm -r nano-4.7
```

Of course you could choose a different prefix (e.g. $HOME or $HOME/.local), or set different directories for different installed file (executable binaries, libraries, header files etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Try [`micro`](https://micro-editor.github.io/), a versatile text editor with **no dependencies**, (IOW a fully static binary).

> Features
>
> - Easy to Use
>         Micro's number one feature is being easy to install (it's just a    static binary with no dependencies) and easy to use.
> - Highly Customizable
>        Use a simple json format to configure your options and rebind keys to    your liking. If you need more power, you can use Lua to
>     configure the    editor further.
> - Colors and Highlighting
>        Micro supports over 75 languages and has 7 default colorschemes to    choose from. Micro supports 16, 256, and truecolor themes.
>     Syntax    files and colorschemes are also very simple to make.
> - Multiple Cursors
>        Micro has support for Sublime-style multiple cursors, giving you lots    of editing power directly in your terminal.
> - Plugin System
>        Micro supports a full-blown plugin system. Plugins are written in Lua    and there is a plugin manager to automatically download and
>     install    your plugins for you.
> - Common Keybindings
>        Micro's keybindings are what you would expect from a simple-to-use    editor. You can also rebind any of the bindings
>     without problem in    the *bindings.json* file.
> - Mouse Support
>        Micro has full support for the mouse. This means you can click and    drag to select text, double click select by word, and triple
>     click to    select by line.
> - Terminal Emulator
>        Run a real interactive shell from within micro. You could open up a    split with code on one side and bash on the other -- all from
>     within    micro.

[image: Micro terminal-based editor with text mode tiled windows]

Comment: Please expand your answer with some additional information. What are its significant features? How big it is, considering the static linking? Does it really not depend on anything, even a C library? What is its UI like? etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try [nano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano). 
This editor is written in C, so it should have not much dependencies, and is much easier to use than vi.

Comment: nano depends on the ncurses library's headers - which as I've explained my distro doesn't have. So, please update your answer to include that and any other dependencies.